# Bash -c awk gives different result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

My current shell is bash, but

```
echo '1 2 3 4'| awk '{print $2}'
```

and

```
bash -c " echo '1 2 3 4'| awk '{print $2}' "
```

gives different result. Os is Linux. What's wrong on second statement?

Comment: @hek2mgl I feel like the answers to the question you linked as duplicate aren't enough to answer OP's problem.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: @hek2mgl The accepted answer of the other question would prompt to use single-quotes to preserve literals, but that's not easily adaptable to a `bash -c` command because of the double expansion and the difficulty to write single quotes in a text that is enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: If I had the same problem and was only told to use single-quotes, I feel like I would come back to ask how I am supposed to do so. Maybe I would first try to escape them with `\'` as most characters are escaped.

Comment: Instead of coming back and ask, I would try "how to escape single quote inside single quoted string" on Google. Please make no big science out of this.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'd sure love people to be more autonomous, but that's not the point. I just feel like the other answer doesn't answers OP's specific problem, and I think I've stated why. Now if you don't agree that's OK, if it really bothered me I'd have voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a HERE-document?

```
bash <<'EOH'
echo '1 2 3 4'| awk '{print $2}'
EOH
```

Note that I have dropped the -c option to bash, and that the single quotes around *EOH* are necessary to avoid evaluating $2 on the shell level.

Comment: Yes, this also works, thanks a lot !

Comment: Nicer than my solution. I'm curious what you mean with `EOH` though (any string can be used, and the norm is to use EOF for `End Of File`). Edit : nvm, `End Of Heredoc` I suppose.

Comment: This solution is different from the other solution. This solution passes the commands to bash over `stdin`. Other solution (and question) passes them as command line arguments to bash.

Comment: Not a single word about double quotes?

Comment: @Aaron : EOH = "end of here-document". You can alternatively write "MGB" (= My grandmother's birthday).

Comment: @anishsane : This is correct, but in this example, the outcome is the same.  Do you see a case where this distinction is important?

Comment: @hek2mgl : Could you elaborate further? In what respect should we discuss double quotes?

Comment: @user1934428 about anishsane's comment : it would be important if `bash -c` was used to provide positional parameters (it considers following parameters as positional parameters for the command). In this specific case I don't think it matters

Comment: I am saying that for this case - bash being the binary to be run - these 2 mechanisms will give the same output. Your solution is more readable because it does not need escaping of quotes. However, for some other binary, that may not be the case. So, while your solution works for this case, OP should understand that the other solution is different and for some other binary, that solution will be required; not this one.

Comment: What @hek2mgl said is that you have given a solution without mentioning why OP's code does not work.

Comment: @anishsane: I see now what you mean. You're right. Fortunately, Aaron's response already explains it.

Answer (score 2):

In your second command, `$2` is evaluated before being handed to `awk`, which gives the following command :

```
echo "1 2 3 4" | awk "{print }"
```

To avoid this, you can use this awful syntax :

```
bash -c 'echo "1 2 3 4"| awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"''
```

Or this syntax suggested by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) :

```
bash -c $'echo "1 2 3 4" | awk \'{print $2}\''
```

The problem is that variable expansion is done twice here : a first time when the `bash -c` command is evaluated, and a second time when the spawned `bash` process evaluates its command line.

My initial answer was to change the command to `bash -c 'echo "1 2 3 4"| awk "{ print $2 }'"`, which indeed avoided expansion in your current shell. However, in the spawned `bash` process, expansion was executed on the following command :

```
echo "1 2 3 4" | awk "{print $2 }"
```

And `$2` was expanded to the empty string.

So we need this command to be executed by the spawned `bash` :

```
echo "1 2 3 4" | awk '{print $2 }'
```

And we need to surround it with single quotes in the current shell :

```
bash -c 'echo "1 2 3 4" | awk '{print $2 }''
```

Except here the `awk` quotes close the `bash -c` parameter's quotes, which leads to the above command where we use `'"'"'` to write a single quote inside a singe-quoted text.

Comment: I have already thought about it and tried, but same result

Comment: @RovshanMusayev sorry you're right, I should have checked my command. I'll delete this answer while I check what's wrong.

Comment: @RovshanMusayev I've found a command that works, but I'm pretty sure it could be done more elegantly. I'll edit if I find one, or you might want to wait for another answer

Comment: Fine, it works thanks. :)

Comment: In `bash`, you can use `$'echo "1 2 3 4" | awk \'{print $2}\''` instead.

Comment: @chepner thanks, that's much prettier than `'"'"'` !